# Why concatenated email addresses aren't printing correctly?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that loads names and email addresses from a file, and then tries to concatenate them into a single string to use to send an email. The email address line needs to be a comma separated list of addresses in the form `Name <email address>, ...`.

I expect it to produce a final output of

```
To: John and Julie <john@example.com>, John and Julie <julie@example.com>, Bobby and Liz <bobby@example.net>, Kevin and Jayme <kevin3248@example.com>, Kevin and Jayme <jayme8396@example.com>, Ellen and Mike <mike397987@example.com>, Ellen and Mike <ellen397286@example.com>,
```

but instead it is producing only

```
>,
```

The following is the full output from the program on my Mac running the latest version of Sierra and Perl 5.18.2.

```
on master* perl example.pl
EmailConfig initialized: John and Julie = john@example.com,julie@example.com
EmailConfig initialized: Bobby and Liz = bobby@example.net
EmailConfig initialized: Kevin and Jayme = kevin3248@example.com,jayme8396@example.com
EmailConfig initialized: Ellen and Mike = mike397987@example.com,ellen397286@example.com
john@example.com
julie@example.com
bobby@example.net
kevin3248@example.com
jayme8396@example.com
mike397987@example.com
ellen397286@example.com
>, on master* <ellen397286@example.com
```

I seem to be reading in all the emails correctly since I can print each one individually, but I'm not sure if the problem in the script is the concatenation or the printing of the final concatenated value.

#### Main Perl program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use EmailConfig;
use File::Slurp;

# Turn off output buffering
$| = 1;

my @emailConfig = ();

sub main() {
    loadConfig();
    processDataAndSendEmail();
}

main();

sub loadConfig() {

    my @raw_configs = read_file('email_config.txt');

    foreach my $raw_config ( @raw_configs ) {

        my $newEmailConfig = new EmailConfig();
        $newEmailConfig->init($raw_config);
        push @emailConfig, $newEmailConfig;
    }
}

sub processDataAndSendEmail() {

    my $to = '';

    foreach my $config ( @emailConfig ) {

        foreach my $email ( @{ $config->{emails} } ) {

            print "$email\n";
            $to .= "$config->{name} <$email>, ";
        }
    }

    print "To: $to";
}
```

#### EmailConfig.pm

```
package EmailConfig;

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

my $emailConfigRegex = qr/(?<email_name>.*) = (?<email_addresses>.*)/;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub init {
    my $self = shift;

    my $emailConfigValue = shift;

    if ($emailConfigValue =~ $emailConfigRegex) {
        $self->{name} = $+{email_name};
        @{$self->{emails}} = split(';', $+{email_addresses});
    }

    my $print_emails = join(",", @{$self->{emails}});
    print "EmailConfig initialized: $self->{name} = $print_emails\n";
}

1;
```

#### email_config.txt

```
John and Julie = john@example.com;julie@example.com
Bobby and Liz = bobby@example.net
Kevin and Jayme = kevin3248@example.com;jayme8396@example.com
Ellen and Mike = mike397987@example.com;ellen397286@example.com
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your expected output in the form that you see (not inline) and what you got instead. And if there are any edits that will get you closer to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the better off we'll all be. When I run your code, it looks like I'm getting what you wanted. Maybe you're running code that you did *not* paste into your question?

Comment: When I run your code, I get the output you expect. So the problem would appear to be in your environment.

Comment: @jeff6times7 The code I pasted is exactly what I'm running, and the output I get is pasted below.  I'm running on perl 5.18.2 on the latest version of Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: `on master* perl example.pl
EmailConfig initialized: John and Julie = john@example.com,julie@example.com
EmailConfig initialized: Bobby and Liz = bobby@example.net
EmailConfig initialized: Kevin and Jayme = kevin3248@example.com,jayme8396@example.com
EmailConfig initialized: Ellen and Mike = mike397987@example.com,ellen397286@example.com
john@example.com
julie@example.com
bobby@example.net
kevin3248@example.com
jayme8396@example.com
mike397987@example.com
ellen397286@example.com
>, on master* <ellen397286@example.com
`

Comment: Sorry, but the output above lost all its carriage returns

Comment: You should add information to your question by editing it, especially if it is multi-line data. But isn't that output already in the question?

Comment: This isn't the source of your problem, but you shouldn't use prototypes on Perl subroutines unless you understand exactly what they do; they are unlike prototypes in other languages. So just `sub main { ... }` etc. is correct.

Comment: @SouthernKnight: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44961925/edit) to add this extra information. Comments are for simple text as (as you've seen) don't allow much formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output, I suspect there's a '\r' character after email adress. Check line endings in email_config.txt, or remove \r character.

```
sub init {
...
    (my $email_addresses = $+{email_addresses})=~s/\r//g;
    @{$self->{emails}} = split(';', $email_addresses);
...
}
```

Comment: The \r appears to be the issue.  I changed the EmailConfig.pm to use a different regex so it wouldn't read to the end of the line, and after that it is working fine.                                           my $emailConfigRegex = qr/(?<email_name>.*) = (?<email_addresses>(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b)+,?)/;